# how to install an ubuntu server with everything that the ubuntu desktop has?

Tags: 14.04, server, raid

how to install an ubuntu server with everything that the ubuntu desktop have? I am using 14.04 on a fresh server with raid disks

Comment: Why don't you just install Ubuntu Desktop then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a meta package called [ubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-desktop) that contains all packages you need for the desktop.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: 2,041 MB of update!!! wahahaha... lazy me...

Comment: does that mean that i cannot fallback into ubuntu server?

Comment: Sure you can: remove those packages again. But, I would decide first rather than installing/removeing 2GBs of packages. Your system can become inconsistent.